# How to merge all csv files in a folder, but they all have different names

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've been searching for a way to merge all csv files in a folder. They all have the same headers, but different names. I've found some videos on youtube on merge and some questions here on stackoverflow that touches the matter. The problem is that this tutorials are focused on files with the same name as: sales1, sales2, etc.

In my case, all files in the directory are CSVs and are located in 'D:\XXXX\XXXX\output'

The code I have used is:

```
import pandas as pd

# set files path
amazon = r'D:\XXXX\XXXX\output\amazonbooks.csv'
bookcrossing = r'D:\XXXX\XXXX\output\bookcrossing.csv'

# merge files
dataFrame = pd.concat(
   map(pd.read_csv, [amazon, bookcrossing]), ignore_index=True)
print(dataFrame)
```

If the code could merge all the files that stand in the folder output (since all of them are .csv), instead of naming each one of them, it would be better.

I'd be glad if anyone can help me with this problem, or can guide me on how to solve this.

Comment: Is there any commonality? For instance, all files in the directory are CSVs. Or perhaps they end with a common suffix like `.csv`? One option is to open all of the files one by one and see if the first line is the header you want.

Comment: Use one of those other answers you mentioned, but change it to accept all files instead of specific filenames.

Comment: Show some code of how you've attempted to solve the problem and include a few example file names you are dealing with. And mention whether the file name itself is important - for instance, it may hold a date that you want added to the csv. With so little information given, we are just guessing here.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have edited the question to complement it more.

Comment: And what do you mean by "merge"? Are they all the same and you just want to append them all into a single result with the same header?

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to append the files into a single result, you don't really need any CSV processing at all. Just write the file contents minus the header line (except the first one). `glob` will return file names with path that match the pattern, "*.csv".

```
from glob import glob
import os
import shutil

csv_dir = r'D:\XXXX\XXXX\output'
result_csv = r'd:\XXXX\XXXX\combined.csv'
first_hdr = True

# all .csv files in the directory have the same header
with open(result_csv, "w", newline="") as result_file:
    for filename in glob(os.path.join(csv_dir, "*.csv")):
        with open(filename) as in_file:
            header = in_file.readline()
            if first_hdr:
                result_file.write(header)
                first_hdr = False
            shutil.copyfileobj(in_file, result_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

(assuming all csvs have equal number of columns)
Try something like this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

csvs = [file for file in os.listdir('D:\XXXX\XXXX\output\') if file.endswith('.csv')]

result_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f'D:\XXXX\XXXX\output\{file}') for file in csvs])
```